# MYSQL - Creating a view/table which mirrors an Oracle table connected by ODBC

Tags: mysql, oracle, replication, mirror

Does anyone know if its possible to create a DB, Table or View in MYSQL which mirrors or replicates a table from an Oracle DB accessable through an ODBC connection.

I basically want to be able to reference say an up to date table of customers in the Oracle DB but from within the MYSQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this might work if you can make your Oracle table a synonym in mySQL. (I'm not too familiar with mySQL syntax though)

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS (SELECT * FROM othertable);
```